# Getting Error when Enabling Https on `CapRover`

Tags: caprover

When enabling https on CapRover got the following error:

```
1107 : Unexpected output when enabling SSL forcaptain. with ACME Certbot Saving debug log to /var/log/letsencrypt/letsencrypt.log Plugins selected: Authenticator webroot, Installer None Obtaining a new certificate Performing the following challenges: http-01 challenge for captain.cr.<your sub-domain> Using the webroot path /captain-webroot/captain.cr.<your sub-domain> for all unmatched domains. Waiting for verification... [31mChallenge failed for domain captain.cr.<your sub-domain>[0m http-01 challenge for captain.cr.<your sub-domain> Cleaning up challenges [31mSome challenges have failed.[0m [1m IMPORTANT NOTES: [0m - The following errors were reported by the server: Domain: captain.cr.<your sub-domain> Type: connection Detail: Fetching http://captain.cr.<your sub-domain>/.well-known/acme-challenge/<your-challenge-hash>: Timeout during connect (likely firewall problem) To fix these errors, please make sure that your domain name was entered correctly and the DNS A/AAAA record(s) for that domain contain(s) the right IP address. Additionally, please check that your computer has a publicly routable IP address and that no firewalls are preventing the server from communicating with the client. If you're using the webroot plugin, you should also verify that you are serving files from the webroot path you provided.
```

Answer (score 0):

Error message pointed to the right issue - `firewall problem`

After configuring firewall to open port 80 the problem got resolved.

p.s. ❤️ love CapRover (on Hetzner)